# How to achieve strong consistency in MongoDB Replica Sets?

Tags: mongodb, replication, distributed-system

In MongoDB documentation, [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/read-preference/), it has been mentioned that in a replica set even with majority readConcern we would achieve eventual consistency. I am wondering how is this possible when we have majority in both reads and writes which leads to a quorum (R+W>N) in our distributed system? I expect a strong consistent system in this setting. This is the technique which Cassandra uses as well in order to achieve strong consistency.

Can someone clarify this for me please?

Answer (score 6):

MongoDb is not regarded very well in terms of strong consistency. If you have a typical sharded and replicated setup to increase consistency will need to trade off some of the performance of the db. As you know you can execute write operations only on the master of the replica set. By default you can only read from it as well. This is possibly the strongest consistency you can get from MongoDb AFAIK as the other nodes are used only for replication, failover and availability reasons. And you could read from the secondary nodes only for operations where having the latest data is not crucial and for long-running operations, such as aggregation for example.

If you set up sharding you could offload a big portion of the read/write operations to different primary nodes. I think that when it comes to MongoDb that is all you could do in order to increasing consistency and performance in particular for larger data sets.

Comment: You are talking about performance and scalability in reads and writes which can be handled through sharding. Eventual consistency is only matters when you want to use secondary nodes in a replica set for read operations. My question is why we dont have strong consistency even though we have a quruom?

Comment: The quorum is only necessary when electing a primary. It cannot account for network lag/delay and the primary is not obliged to wait for the write transaction to be replayed on all the secondaries just for the sake of consistency. Imagine this scenario - having two ssd based nodes for performance and failover and a cheaper hdd node for backups. Should the high performance primary node wait for the operation to complete on the slowest member?

Comment: majority vote is needed for primary election. Quorum means Readers+Writers>No of nodes. This expression is true when we set both readConcern and writeConcern to majority. So when we read from a majority of nodes there is at least one node that has the latest write, and so, the system is strongly consistent. I want to know why this expression is not true about MongoDB?